# How do I show scenario name instead of feature name in Cucumber html report

Tags: java, jenkins, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

By default cucumber report shows feature names.
Since I have several scenarios within 1 feature file,
I want to display scenario name instead of feature name.
To make the report more verbose
My Cucumber options are:

```
 cucumberOptions = @CucumberOptions(
            features = "src/test/resources/features",
            monochrome = true,
            glue = "stepDefinitions",
            tags = {"not @disable"},
            plugin = {
                    "pretty",
                    "json:build/cucumber-report/cucumber.json",
                    "html:build/cucumber-report/cucumber.html"},
            strict = true
    )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My report is showing scenario information also . I am using [`courgette-jvm`](https://github.com/prashant-ramcharan/courgette-jvm) with `testNG` here is my setup

```
package com.test;

import courgette.api.CourgetteOptions;
import courgette.api.CourgetteRunLevel;
import courgette.api.CucumberOptions;
import courgette.api.testng.TestNGCourgette;
import io.cucumber.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
    @Test
    @CourgetteOptions(
            threads = 10,
            runLevel = CourgetteRunLevel.SCENARIO,
            rerunFailedScenarios = true,
            rerunAttempts = 1,
            showTestOutput = true,
            reportTitle = "Courgette-JVM Example",
            reportTargetDir = "build",
            environmentInfo = "browser=chrome; git_branch=master",
            cucumberOptions = @CucumberOptions(
                    features = "src/test/resources/com/test/",
                    glue = "com.test.stepdefs",
                    //tags = {"@post or @get"},
                    publish = true,
                    plugin = {
                            "pretty",
                            "json:target/cucumber-report/cucumber.json",
                            "html:target/cucumber-report/cucumber.html"}
            ))
    class AcceptanceIT extends TestNGCourgette {
    }
```

package com.test;

[image: cucumber report]

[image: cucumber report with steps]